# Electron Crashing On Exception, Even With uncaughtException Handled

Tags: node.js, exception, electron

Im trying to prevent my application crashing when and unhandled exception occurs.

I've added a

```
process.on("uncaughtException", err => {
  dialog.showErrorBox("Uh oh...", `${err}`);
});
```

and im just triggering a false exception by calling a function that doesn't exist inside of a main process method, triggered by a button click and an IPC call from the rendered UI.

```
start() {
  this.blah(); // ReferenceError blah is not defined
}
```

to my main process file, although now I just get two dialogs, the first default electron one, showing the stack track and error, then the one prompted by me, followed by the application crashing.

So it appears it's hitting the uncaught exception handler, although it just pops up the dialog and continues.

How can I prevent the app from crashing, and only display the one dialog box from my handler?

Comment: what crash are you getting out of curiosity? also, for the reasons stated [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception), you shouldn't be prevent crashes and continuing on. You really should exit the application. Does the error dialog that electron shows have the same error was the one in the uncaughtException handler?

Comment: In fact, the fact that you're continuing on might be the problem. It might be running into another error and dying for some reason.

Comment: Im calling a method in the main process from the renderer. Im triggering the exception manually by creating a bad variable to test.  The error is "A Javascript error occurred in the browser process".  The code most definitely lives in the main process though, being being triggered via ipc from the UI

Comment: show how you're triggering the exception. and is the second error you get the same as the first?

Comment: can you confirm that you see the same error in the two popups, or are they two different ones? We'll probably need more context to diagnose this, since I can't reproduce this. My app shows a single error dialog and continues running